# Mail function in php not sending through

Tags: php, forms

My Php code originally sent through an email, using this exact function however now i have tried to alter the header so the email didnt come through as @backend1.freehosting.com and the function does not work.

My code is:

```
<?php
    // display form if user has not clicked submit
    if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
        From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
        Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
    </form>
<?php 
    }else {
        // the user has submitted the form
        // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
        if (isset($_POST["from"])) {
            $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
            $subject = $_POST["subject"];
            $message = $_POST["message"];
            // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
            // send mail
            $headers = 'From: me@mysitedomain.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: me@mysitedomain.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail("example@hotmail.com",$subject,$message,$headers);
            echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This probably has been answered countless times before you need a mailserver running on your server and if you do it can still be seen as spam.

Comment: Probably a spam issue. Do you have proof that it's leaving your server? I always use swiftmailer to perform email operations, it works a treat every time.

Comment: how do i find if it is leaving my server, as it is a free dev env using free hosting, so i am unfamiliar with it.

also - Its not coming into my spam box either

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: nope, just no email whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Usually, mail log including errors are sent to your systems mail server log directory. If you are using CentOS / RHEL / Redhat or Fedora Linux, check `/var/log/maillog` file using any one of the following command:

NOTE: Needs to have ssh access on the server

```
tail -f /var/log/maillog

grep 'user@example.com' /var/log/maillog

more /var/log/maillog
```

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian Linux, check `/var/log/mail.err` and `/var/log/mail.log` files:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log

tail -f /var/log/mail.err
```